# Check if the input of variable is in xx.xx.xxxx format

Tags: python

I have a variable "ver" whose input should be of the format xx.xx.xxxx ,valid and invalid examples below,can any one suggest how to check the input of "ver" is in this format?

```
VALID INPUTS:-

ver = 00.00.0009



INVALID INPUTS:-

ver = 000.0.11
ver = 00.00.002
ver = 0.0.0001
......
```

Comment: And are only `0` and `1` allowed?

Comment: @no - any integer is allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) :

```
import re
if re.match(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$',input) :
      #do stuff
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4MThhjOl4gB3pbvE)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions using the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) :

```
import re
valid = re.match('\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}', ver)
if valid:
   #...
```